# How can I interpret mov ds:dword_4870058 , offset loc_4048E0?

Tags: assembly

I have the following assembly line and I have my problems to understand it, because until now I have always seen lines like this: `mov eax, 0` and so on. 
But now, I have the following (I use IDA PRO):

```
 mov ds:dword_4870058 , offset loc_4048E0
```

When I click on offset `loc_4048E0`, I see:

```
 loc_4048E0:
 mov al, 10h
 jmp sub_402774
```

when I interpret `dword_4870058` as a global variable, can I assume that `dword_4870058` gets the value `10h` (if I regard `al` as a return value register) . This is the only thing that I can imagine.

Is it a right or wrong assumption ?

Comment: No. loc_4048E0 SEEMS to be a function. if so dword_4870058 is a function pointer (and a global variable as you already found out), if not it is a pointer to data that for some reason IDA seems to think of as a function (No idea how likely IDA mislabels that)

Comment: I thought that the mov-instruction is for storing data/content. Is it different when it is a function pointer, or ? I mean, is there a reason why the compiler pick mov instead of lea ?

Comment: lea / mov difference is covered pretty well here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner version would be:

```
mov [dword_4870058] , offset loc_4048E0
```

Then, a variant:

```
mov [address], value
```

Where, the `[ ]` signifies its a memory address contained within the `[]`
and the value put in it for this case is another memory address (in the code section).

To move it to a register it would be:

```
mov register, value ; eg : mov eax, 12345678h
```

The value portion can be a value, a pointer, a constant... They're all the same ... just numbers.

Little thing to pay in mind, in x86 you cant do memory to memory moves. So, the "can I assume that `dword_4870058` gets the value `10h`" is completely wrong, the function at that address has NOT been called has it ? So, it cant get the value `10h`...

Its simply storing one value (the address of a function) into another memory block.

Comment: And presumably, the OP would find something like `call ds:[dword_4870058]` somewhere else in the code. Whether or not that will call *this particular function* needs a full flow trace to find out if it's a constant (once written, never modified), or only can be determined during run-time.